# Create github machine user without creating github user?

Tags: github

I'm confused about github machine users. I want to add an ssh key with read only rights to my repo to use for automation and have it tied to my repository/organization. But it seems like I need to create an actual github user that is not scoped to anything. I'm referring to where you add a collaborator by "Search by username, full name or email address". This seems like a poor match for what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to create a machine user that can be managed by the organization without creating a github user?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a *sine qua non* that an ssh key is associated with a user, so you must create a user. See https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users

GitHub says it's "totally cool" to create a single machine user for automation.